# Are there any books or articles that contain information on the P weak omega or second order predicate calculi?

Tags: lambda-calculus, dependent-type, typed-lambda-calculus

I have been trying to learn about the lambda cube, but cannot find any sources covering the P weak omega and P2 nodes.  Is the problem that these nodes are not frequently used/ offer little benefits over the calculus of constructions?  Thanks

Comment: What's the "P weak omega"? Can you link to the reference you have in mind?

Comment: It is mentioned in "An Introduction to generalized type systems" in the journal of Functional Programming, April 1991.  https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/wadler/papers/barendregt/pure-type-systems.pdf mentioned on page five of the linked PDF.  Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I've talked about a couple of these in [this](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/36054/3984) question, though Neel's answer gives a lot of insight as well, though I didn't dwell on $\lambda P_\underline{\omega}$ specifically.

$\lambda P_2$ is quite famous: it's the dependent type theory corresponding to second-order predicate logic. I think Geuvers has written about it (e.g. [here](http://www.cs.ru.nl/%7Eherman/PUBS/IndNonder.pdf). It's a good place to do math in, in fact you pretty rarely need the extra power of the CoC, though it is convenient.

$\lambda P_\underline\omega$ is *not* second order, so you cannot quantify over predicates, e.g. as in $\forall P:\star, P \rightarrow P$, indeed you only have a little more expressive power over simple first order logic.

One thing you *can* do in this system is express *predicate transformers*. For example, in the context $\mathbb{N} : \star$ one could declare

$$\mathrm{Exists}:(\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \star)\rightarrow \star$$

That is, you can give a type to the $\exists$ operator, which is not possible in $\lambda P$ proper.

I'm not sure anyone's studied this system on its own though.

Comment: Wow, thank you! that thread and the article is very useful.  I couldnt quite believe that nobody had published any papers on lambda P weak omega ever so wanted to make sure.

Comment: I don't know of any work that looks at it specifically.